# shell script: cut part of a string

Tags: bash, scripts

I have following string

```
11-22-33-44-55-66-77-88-99-1010-1111-1212
```

I want to extract 88-99-1010-111 from that string

Comment: You really want 111 or 1111 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
echo 11-22-33-44-55-66-77-88-99-1010-1111-1212 | awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="-"} {print $8,$9,$10,$11}'
```

- `BEGIN {FS=OFS="-"}` is used to set both the field separator (`FS`) and the output field separator (`OFS`) to `-`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cut`:

Based on delimiter and fields:

```
echo 11-22-33-44-55-66-77-88-99-1010-1111-1212 | cut -d- -f 8-11
```

Based on character position:

```
echo 11-22-33-44-55-66-77-88-99-1010-1111-1212 | cut -c 22-36
```

Or use bash [parameter substition](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

```
var=11-22-33-44-55-66-77-88-99-1010-1111-1212
echo ${var:21:15}
```